# Why won't my function calculations print correctly?

Tags: c++, function, file

So I am working on a question for school, a code that takes a file and scans the data inside to print back the names and numerous BMI index numbers. I've gotten everything else running smoothly right now but there's a problem with the calculations for the BMI index. For this problem I am calculating BMI by doing

weight (lb) * 703 / height (inches)^2

I created a variable to add all the inches together to make things more simple. The calculations are at the bottom in the function calcBMI.

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//prototypes
double calcBMI(double, double, double ); 
string calcCategory(double);

int main() 
{
    string inputFile;
    //opening file 
    cout << "Enter input file name: "; 
    cin >> inputFile;
    ifstream input; 
    input.open(inputFile, ios::in);
    //storing something in output file 
    string outputFile;
    cout << "Enter output file name: "; 
    cin >> outputFile;
    ofstream output;
    output.open(outputFile, ios::out);
    //verfying if file opened 
    if(input.is_open()) 
    {
        string row, name, temp;
        double weight, feet, inches; 
        //read line
        while(getline(input, row)) 
        {

            //string stream
            stringstream ss(row); 

            int i = 0;

            //split with #
            while(getline(ss, temp, '#')) 
            {
                if(i == 0) {
                    name = temp;
            }
                else 
                {
                    stringstream sss(temp);  
                    sss >> weight >> feet >> inches;
                }
                i++;
            }

            double BMI = calcBMI(weight, feet, inches);
            string category = calcCategory(BMI);

            //print results
            output << "Helath profile for " << name << endl;
            output << "BMI: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << BMI << "\tCategory: " << category << endl << endl;
            
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "File not found" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

//bmi calculator 
double calcBMI(double weight, double feet , double inches) 
{
    double totalinches = (feet * 12) + inches;
    double BMI = (weight * 703) / totalinches * totalinches;
    return BMI;
}

//category calculator 
string calcCategory(double BMI) 
{
    if(BMI < 18.5) 
    {
        return "UnderWeight";
    }
    else if(BMI < 25) 
    {
        return "Normal";
    }
    else if(BMI < 30) 
    {
        return "OverWeight";
    }
    else 
    {
        return "Obese";
    }
}
```

What happens is it only multiplies the weight by 703 but it won't divide by the denominator. Any suggestions?

Comment: order of operations, `(weight * 703) / totalinches * totalinches` is actually `((weight * 703) / totalinches) * totalinches`, see the mistake now?

Comment: Unrelated, this code won't compile as-presented on my rig because it isn't compliant with includes. [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) mandates inclusion of `<sstream>`, which you're not doing. Play by the rules and everyone wins.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out a solution to this

```
double calcBMI(double weight, double feet , double inches) 
{
    double totalinches = (feet * 12) + inches;
    double BMI = weight * 703 / (((feet * 12) + inches) * ((feet * 12) + inches));
    return BMI;
}
```

A bit complicated but still works. Cheers